# Create new columns from existing columns in R loop?

Tags: r, loops

Within a dataframe, I have a set of columns for which I would like to create a new set of columns. Specifically, from columns 4 through 8 and 11 through 13, I would like to create new columns that are lagged versions of each of these columns.

Without applying a for loop, for each individual column, my lagging code looks like this:
`df$FIREmob_l1 <- lag(df$FIREmob, 50L)`

However, I would like to apply a loop so that a new column "colname"_l1 is created by applying `lag(df$"colname", 50L)` to columns 5 through 8 and 11 through 13.

My two main issues:

1. How do I specify in a loop that I only want the loop to run over particular columns in a dataframe?
2. How can I indicate I want a new variable created for each variable that called "'colname'_1L"?

Thanks!

I am confused where to even begin.

Comment: i would do this but to each their own `nm <- names(df)[c(4:8, 11:13)]; df[, paste0(nm, '_1L')] <- lapply(df[, nm], function(x) lag(x, 50))`

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` provides a very easy way to accomplish this

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- df |>
  mutate( 
    across(c(col4:col8, col11:col15), # replace with the names of your actual columns
      list(
        l1 = ~lag(.x, 50L)
      )
  )
```

To address your two questions specifically:

the `across` function requires two arguments.
(1)  The first is a vector of column names that you want to apply a function to.  Here, I've specified them as `col4:col8` and `col11:col13`, but you'd replace that with your actual column names.

(2) The second is a function or list of functions.  Here, we're using a list of size 1 in order specify that new variables need to be created instead of overwriting the original variables.  By default (we are getting lucky here), it uses the format `"{.col}_{.fn}"`, where `.col` is the column name and `.fn` is the function name, so by naming the function `l1`, you get what you want.  If you wanted to do something else, you could add another argument to `across`: `.name`, where you specify how to include the column name and function name into the new variable name (e.g. `.name = "{.fn}_{.col}"` would give the reverse order).

If you are not familiar with the pipe operator (`|>`), an equivalent representation is

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- mutate(df, 
    across(c(col4:col8, col11:col15), # replace with the names of your actual columns
      list(
        l1 = ~lag(.x, 50L)
      )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide a working example, so I can't test this, but I think this is what you are after:

```
# Use apply to efficiently loop over the columns.
# Just supply the loop with the columns you are interested in.
lagged.columns = apply(df[, c(4:8, 11:13)], 2, lag, 50L)
```

If you want to add the lagged columns to the original data.frame, just use `cbind`.

```
df = cbind(df, lagged.columns)
```